# Getting 302 on delete http method using rest ssured

Tags: rest-assured, http-status-code-302

I am new to rest assured testing.
I am doing authentication using cookies and the GET call is returning a 200 status but when i am doing a delete, i am getting 302. What am i doing wrong?

**This works-**

```
        public void Getcall(String id){
        RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
        String c= driver.manage().getCookies().toString();
        Response response= RestAssured.given().when().baseUri("service url"+id).cookie(c).**get** 
        ().then().extract().response();
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());

    }
```

**This does not work-** (gives 302)

```
        public void softDeleteCal(){
        RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
        String c= driver.manage().getCookies().toString();
        Response response= RestAssured.given().when().baseUri("service url"+id").cookie(c).**delete** 
        ().then().extract().response();
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
    }
```

This is format of cookie from the chrome developers console> network tab
Cookie: **VCAP_ID**=fdf425dd-80e3-4820-757b-73c6; JSESSIONID=AA5B704E5DC85CACEADFF09D61084A06

Comment: When you are doing a `delete`, what is the expected status code ?

Comment: @wilfred-clement-   Expected status code is 200 and it works fine when i run it on HTTP client on IntelliJ.

Comment: Fair enough, add a `.log().all()` after `given()` , `then()` and compare the request traffic